# Using result of a formula to create an external reference

Tags: excel

I've been having a problem with getting my external references to be more dynamic and working with formulas.

What I am trying to do is use the result of a formula (which should be a text string) in my external reference.

If I type in my external reference name manually as shown below, then the reference works.

```
='C:\Users\ltbaumann\Dropbox (EPC Services Testing)\!_Billings Testing-Current Projects\15-1203 Hidalgo AMSC\[15-1203_!!!_Project Details Sheet.xlsx]Sheet1'!B2
```

The problem arises when I want to use my formula to provide all of the filepath info up to the "[".

Here is the formula that gets the filepath.

```
  =LEFT(CELL("filename",A1),FIND("?",SUBSTITUTE(CELL("filename",A1),"\","?",LEN(CELL("filename",A1))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(CELL("filename",A1),"\",""))-2)))
```

Here is the result of that formula.

```
C:\Users\ltbaumann\Dropbox (EPC Services Testing)\!_Billings Testing-Current Projects\15-1203 Hidalgo AMSC\
```

How can I use the results of that formula in the external reference?
Note: The workbook for reference will not be open so I dont think that INDIRECT() will work. The reason that I am not manually entering the Filepath as text is because these files are in a dropbox and thus the filepath will be different across different machines.

Thanks for the help! Hopefully I was clear enough.